# Bolt modifying an record from the web page. Using Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, bolt-cms

Im trying to modify records from my wep page using bolt, for lets say an comment section. If someone posts an answer underneath an news item how do i put that info into an record. And if they want to edit their reaction how would I update it.

So i was trying something at this point with the status. My base status is always published.

```
{{ record.status == draft }}  <-- tried this way
{% set record.status == record.status = draft %} <-- tried SET  
{% set record.status == record.status = "draft" %} <-- tried adding ""
```

After my try and error period I went to all the documentation on bolt and twig. But I cant seem to find out how to do this.

So I hope someone knows how to do this, thank you in advance.

Comment: did i get it right? you want to edit  records in database  from the  twig ??

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i want to do. is this not possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

short anwser is - you can't  modify database records directly from twig.

Twig it's  template  system (idea is to show data with it) .

To dwhat you want  you need  to write all this "stuff" by  yourself . It can be done (best way  is to learn about creating  custom modules  - but you need to be quite  good with OOPHP , symfony components  etc. )

Comment: Ok thank you very much for the info. ill upvote and hook the answer. as support.

Comment: Twig should only be used to output information, not update it. You prefferably want to use some ajax to do what you want